# correlation loop keep getting NA

Tags: r, for-loop, correlation

Despite using two complete columns where every element is numeric and no numbers are missing for rows 2 thru 570, I find it impossible to get a result other than NA when using a loop to find a rolling 24-week correlation between the two columns.

```
rolling.correlation <- NULL
temp <- NULL
for(i in 2:547){
   temp <- cor(training.set$return.SPY[i:i+23],training.set$return.TLT[i:i+23])
   rolling.correlation <- c(rolling.correlation, temp)
} #end "for" loop

rolling.correlation
```

The cor()command works fine for [2:25], [i:25], or [2:i] but R doesn't understand when I say [i:i+23]

I want R to calculate a correlation for rows 2 thru 25, then 3 thru 26, ..., 547 thru 570. The result should be a vector of length 546 which has numeric values for each correlation. Instead I'm getting a vector of 546 NAs. How can I fix this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually, are you sure *you* understand what `i:i+23` means? Try `5:5+2`. Note that `:` has a higher operator precedence than `+`. Try `i:(i+23)`.

Comment: MrFlick you are a life saver. Parentheses did the trick. Thank you. I'm also a total novice re: how to use apply(). Is there a way to get the same 546-element vector by using apply() instead of a loop? Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: `apply`  **is** a loop. Which way your write it depends largely on your coding style.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it depends on style but I want to be as efficient as possible. I have heard that loops take up a lot of processing time relative to using apply so I would like to add that skill to my repertoire. Can you advise me on how to use apply to accomplish the same thing that I did in the above "for" loop?

Comment: I don't know who told you that, but they were wrong. for loops can often be faster in R, what is slow is appending/memory management but as long as you preallocate potentially growing vectors, then it will be fine. So in your case, do `rolling.correlation <- numeric(256)` and do `rolling.correlation[i-1]<-temp`.

Comment: My R professor told me that loops are typically slower than equivalent commands. From what you're saying, it's not universally true. But since commands can represent more efficient coding, I want to understand how to use them. Thanks for the advice. I will try to use your more recent code. For what types of situations should loops be avoided due to being slow?

Comment: I've used R for many years now and i've never seen a case where a properly coded for-loop was slower than an *apply function. If you make the changes i suggested, the for loop will probably be faster. But this discussion is off-topic from your original question.

Comment: This is a well-known gotcha in R [Canonical question for R gotcha: colon operator takes higher precedence than arithmetic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338980/canonical-question-for-r-gotcha-colon-operator-takes-higher-precedence-than-ari)

Answer (score 1):

Look what happens when you do

```
5:5+2
# [1] 7
```

Note that `:` has a higher operator precedence than `+` which means `5:5+2` is the same as `(5:5)+2` when you really want `5:(5+2)`. Use

```
i:(i+23)
```